# DirectX AudioVideoPlayback Video Background Transparency

Tags: c#, video, directx, audiovideoplayback

I'm playing video on my form using DirectX AudioVideoPlayback. Source code is pretty simple

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Video MyVideo;

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ShowVideo();
    }

    void ShowVideo()
    {
        MyVideo = new Video("bottle.mp4", true);
        MyVideo.Owner = this;            
    }
}
}
```

video itself **bottle.mp4** designed the way that it can have transparent background

http://youtu.be/T35kGZMXg5g

Here are my questions:

1. How can I put my custom background image instead of green video background?
2. How can I make this background transparent? So I can see the bottle and my desktop behind it
3. Is it necessary to have h.264 (.mp4) format video, will this also work with .wmv file?

Thanks.

Comment: Note that this is using the legacy Managed DirectX 1.1 assemblies which in turn use DirectShow. Be sure to read [DirectX and .NET](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2010/12/09/directx-and-net.aspx).

Comment: So as I understood directx SDK is depricated and while my only goal is video, not game development, you'd suggest to use directshow rather than directx?

Comment: DirectShow is the only 'DirectX' component for video, and you get it from the Windows SDK and not the legacy DirectX SDK--it was  moved out of the DirectX SDK back in ~2005. See [DirectX SDKs of a certain age](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/08/22/directx-sdk-s-of-a-certain-age.aspx). The DirectShow.NET wrapper I mention is an option here for C# usage.

Comment: BTW, Direct3D 11.1 (Windows 8.0, [Windows 7 SP1 + KB 2670838](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/02/26/directx-11-1-and-windows-7-update.aspx)) does have "Direct3D 11 Video" which is extremely low-level and you should really look at Media Foundation instead on those platforms.

Comment: So as I understood DirectX is more gaming direction and I should better consider Media Foundation .Net right?

Comment: "DirectX" as a brand is historically about gaming, yes, and primarily 2D and 3D graphics. It's not really so much about video processing. "DirectShow" was really a media project shoved into the "DirectX" brand... it was originally called "ActiveMovie". DirectShow is the legacy video API for Windows that still does some stuff the 'current' video API for Windows doesn't (Media Foundation) and is supported on Windows XP. If you are targeting Windows Vista or later, then you should consider Media Foundation as a first choice for video work on Windows.

Comment: Yes my target is Windows Vista and higher. So I'll try Media Foundation. Thanks Chuck.